# Как отправить несколько фото через telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь сделать отправку 2-ух фото разом.

```
bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open(photo, 'rb')) for photo in ['image0.jpg', 'image1.jpg']])
```

Но они отправляются не совместно. Как сделать отправку совместную?

Comment: ```bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, [
      telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('image0.jpg', 'rb')),
      telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('image1.jpg', 'rb'))
    ])``` а если вот так?

Comment: благодарю за по

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('image0.jpg', 'rb')), telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('image1.jpg', 'rb'))])
```

Comment: На самом деле можно не подставлять руками отдельные фото, вы можете собрать массив и передать его, главное массив собирать не "внутри параметров" функции :)